# file uploading issue in joomla, path and permissions are correct

Tags: file, joomla, permissions, uploading

Hi all I put some code in joomla file and I am facing an issue where destination path and the folder permissions are correct though the file is not uploading

here is the code

```
$avatar_file = JRequest::getVar('image', null, 'files','array');
            $upfilename= str_replace($replace,'_',$avatar_file['name']);
            //echo JPATH_ROOT.DS.'images'.DS.'easyblog_avatar'.DS;
            //exit;
            print_r($_FILES);
            $arr = '{"google_profile_url":"","show_google_profile_url":""}';
            echo is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']).'<br>'.
            //$destFilePath = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).DS.'images'.DS.'easyblog_avatar'.DS.$user_id.'_'.$upfilename;
            $destFilePath = JPATH_ROOT.DS.'images'.DS.'easyblog_avatar'.DS.$user_id.'_'.$upfilename;
            //if(JFile::upload($avatar_file['tmp_name'], JPATH_ROOT.DS.'images'.DS.$user_id.'_'.$upfilename)){
            if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destFilePath)){
                $avatar = $user_id.'_'.$upfilename;
            }
```

I use both joomla functions and the core function for uploading the file, but it is not uploading.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting $_FILES?

Comment: "it is not uploading" is not enough information. Do you get an error ? where does the code fail ? using `@` is not recommended when you want errors to surface.

Comment: @ alfasin yes your correct, but I am not getting any error so i tried '@' although I tried error_reporting('E_ALL'); and ini_set('display_error',1);

Comment: @Irfan yes I'm getting $_FILES

Answer (score 0):

```
    //import joomlas filesystem functions, we will do all the filewriting with joomlas functions
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');

  //this is the name of the field in the html form, filedata is the default name for swfupload
$fieldName = 'Filedata';

    //the name of the file in PHP's temp directory that we are going to move to our folder
    $fileTemp = $_FILES[$fieldName]['tmp_name'];


    //always use constants when making file paths, to avoid the possibilty of remote file inclusion
    $uploadPath = JPATH_SITE.DS.'path'.DS.'path'.DS.$fileName;

    if(!JFile::upload($fileTemp, $uploadPath)) 
    {
            echo JText::_( 'ERROR MOVING FILE' );
            return;
    }
```

Comment: i can use 'jimport' in a function

Comment: file is uploading on temporary folder but is not moving to the destination is there is any reason behind it?

Comment: it might because you are not setting the path right. try to echo the path and see whether that is correct

Comment: i have checked it the path is correct 
out put of the $_FILES

Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => zoomin.gif [type] => image/gif [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpM2yhUx [error] => 0 [size] => 150 ) ) 1

Comment: post the echo of the path here. $_FILES Array seems fine

Comment: is it possible that the temp file may deleted before moving it?

Comment: I guess it's not. It should be the path.